# TinyMCE doesn't style code output using codesample plugin?

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I'm tried to implement tinyMCE in Laravel project, idea is to output PHP code stylized, like it looks at input. Shouldn't [codesample](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/) plugin work like that or am I wrong.

**TinyMCE integration:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea.tinymce-editor',
            width: "100%",
            height: "700",
            mode: "exact",
            menubar: 'file edit insert view format table tools help',
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                'searchreplace visualblocks fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media table paste help wordcount codesample'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect |' +
                'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
                'removeformat | help codesample',
            content_css: '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
        });
    </script>
```

**How input looks:**

[image]

**And how output looks:**

[image]

**How I print output in blade.php file:**

```
{!! $post->description !!}
```

As you can see output code is not stylized like the input. Is it normal to work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, [codesimple plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/) works with [prism.js](https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript) When I added prism.js and prism.css files, output looks like input. They should be added before TinyMCE configuration.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `codesample` plugin uses `prism.js` to embed code samples into editor content. Prism itself is included within the `codesample` plugin, but that only affects the content while it is in the editor itself. Therefore you should not need external JS or CSS for content to appear properly formatted in the editor.

You will need to add `prism.js` and `prism.css` to the appropriate place in your project for syntax to be highlighted in code samples on your webpage. You can generate these files on the download page at the Prism website.

For more information regarding the `codesample` plugin, check out the docs:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/